# file not saved correctly

Tags: java, android

Im trying to get image using webservice and saved to sd card. The file saved but i couldnt open the file. Once i open the file it saying "could not load image". Below is my code.

```
httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
Object response = envelope.getResponse();
test = response.toString();
Blob picture = org.hibernate.Hibernate.createBlob(test.replaceAll("-", "").getBytes());
String FILENAME = "voucher1.jpg"; 
File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(new File(root, FILENAME));
InputStream x=picture.getBinaryStream();
int size=x.available();
byte b[]= new byte[size];
x.read(b);
f.write(b);
f.close();
```

Please help. Thanks

Comment: what is the content of test, and why would you replace '-' by ''?

Comment: its a byte[] which i convert to string in webservice and return the value here. The reason i replace '-' because when i checked the test string..there was '-' by default...

Comment: this could be a problem. byte[] -> String -> byte[] does not work if you use different encodings, which i highly likely. Also, what is the point of creating a Blob? And if you remove all hyphens, you'll loose parts of your file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the format..instead use web service i just use the image url to retrieve the image and it works...

i try this and its work fine. Thanks.

```
URL url = new URL(fileURL);
URLConnection conexion = url.openConnection();
conexion.connect();
int lenghtOfFile = conexion.getContentLength();
Log.d("ANDRO_ASYNC", "Lenght of file: " + lenghtOfFile);
InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/caldophilus.jpg");
byte data[] = new byte[1024];
long total = 0;
while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
total += count;
output.write(data, 0, count);
}
output.flush();
output.close();
input.close();
```

Answer (score -1):

i assume you need to call **f.flush()** in order to write out all data in stream to file.

```
f.flush();
f.close();
```

Comment: Documentation: "This stream is not buffered. Most callers should wrap this stream with a BufferedOutputStream."  Closing a stream is enough to cause everything to be flushed anyway